# unexpected behavior when adding a static library in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am reviewing a legacy code in C++ in Visual Studio 2008. When adding the **static lib** d3dx9.h it throws the following error at compilation (for a number of files):

```
Compiling...
Menu.cpp
c:\users\jason\desktop\slot project\video_engine.h(33) : fatal error C1083: 
Cannot open include file: 'd3dx9.h': No such file or directory
MAIN.cpp
c:\users\eduardo\desktop\slot project\video_engine.h(33) : fatal error C1083: 
Cannot open include file: 'd3dx9.h': No such file or directory
GameSettings.cpp
c:\users\eduardo\desktop\slot project\video_engine.h(33) : fatal error C1083: 
Cannot open include file: 'd3dx9.h': No such file or directory
...
...
...
```

This lib is included in **video_engine.h**:

```
#include "d3dx9.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "platform\\DirectX\\d3d9.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "platform\\DirectX\\d3dx9.lib")
```

Likewise, the header **video_engine.h** is included directly (#include...) and indirectly (including a file that already included this header...) by a number of files. For instance, **Menu.cpp** does not include this header, but it (Menu.cpp) does include **MAIN.cpp** which includes the header (video_engine.h).

Thanks in advance for any suggestions !

In addition, below the **Property Pages** for **AdditionalIncludeDirectories** and Linker's **AdditionalDependencies** and AdditionalLibraryDirectories:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Well, where is the file d3dx9.h in fact located?  Does it exist at all? You've mentioned a `.lib` file with a related name, but that's an altogether different thing.

Comment: You need to download and install legacy DirectX SDK and then set project include and lib dirs to point at right locations.

Comment: John Bollinger, good comment. The error shown above is having no header at all. when I included in either the project's or platform directory, it throws:

Comment: Compiling...
Menu.cpp
c:\Users\Eduardo\Desktop\Slot Project\platform\d3dx9.h(47) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'd3dx9math.h': No such file or directory

Comment: VTT, the project implements DirectX 9. I downloaded the DirectX SDK, but I am not certain what the legacy is.

Comment: If you've downloaded something named "DirectX SDK" then it is a legacy SDK. Modern DirectX SDK is merged with Windows SDK and is not available as a separate download.

Comment: VTT, OK, got it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error `No such file or directory` usually happens when the compiler cannot find the folder or cannot gain access to a folder or file. Try using **Run as Administrator** for Visual Studio. Also, in the **Additional include directories** you should give the full path of the include directory. most C++ libraries have this structure:

- bin
- lib
- include

If we Assume our lib is in the **C:\** folder, We should enter the:
**C:\Libs\Boost\include**  in the **Additional include directories**.